# Embedded fonts in iOS: why are they not centered correctly on the y axis?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, fonts

I've embedded a couple fonts in my iOS app and am finding that they're not centered correctly in labels and buttons, they're too high on the y axis, is there any solution for this?  At first I thought it was just a cheap font file I was using but then I tried it (just to see) with an Adobe font and it still has the issue.

Comment: I've noticed this too.  Never had time to look into it though. +1!

Comment: Have you checked if your problem is not that you are using only uppercase letters and the labels are being centered as if they had both upper and lower case letters on it (so it's considering some space below for letters like lowercase p and q)?

Comment: I'm using both upper and lowercase letters so thats probably not the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The (a?) solution a friend of mine pointed out is to use the contentEdgeInsets property of the button, I set it to:

```
myButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 0, 0);
```

To bump the text down 10 pixels and now the text is centered.  Woot.

Comment: Its true, fortunately for a label you can just adjust the location of the label, for buttons you're in kind of a bind :)

Answer (score 0):

I've too struggled with this.

Depending on the situation, I'm using different solutions:

- using insets when the element in question supports it
- replacing the label in question with a view, which holds another label as its subview. I then move that new label within it's superview until it is centered. This works with titlebars and the like.

What I have not tried yet is subclassing UILabel (or even better: writing a category on it) to include a fix.

Maybe I'll write a bug report as well.

I'll keep you posted on that!

Answer (score 0):

You should notice that [UIControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) classes have a property [contentVerticalAlignment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/contentVerticalAlignment) (as well as [contentHorizontalAlignment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/contentHorizontalAlignment)).

Answer (score 0):

The centering problem only occurs in UILabels. UITextViews are working properly. UIButton has a UILabel inside, and so, has the same problem.

To fix it, you can correct your font position with a tool like Font Creator. In my case we had to correct it with -200. This way you can use the UILabel as you normally do, no subclassing or extra categories.

Font Creator download link: http://www.high-logic.com/fontcreator.html

Comment: Why should we 'correct' a correct font? It's Apple that displays it wrong... After correcting, the font will look shifted in the y-axis in UITextViews...
Until Apple fixes this, we need to find a better solution I guess..

Comment: Well I had to go on, so I just corrected the font. I agree Apple has to fix it. But that can take years... And I also don't know a better solution.