# How do I center embedded fonts vertically within UILabels?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, fonts, uilabel

In a previous question:

[Embedded fonts in iOS: why are they not centered correctly on the y axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5319157/748718)

it was noted that embedded fonts were not being centered vertically in iOS controls.

A solution was proposed there, but that solution only works with buttons.  How can we properly center embedded fonts within UILabels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a problem with a custom font in iOS that had very tall glyphs so they were getting clipped by the label. Ended creating my own label subclass with self created CATextLayer. This may sound extreme, but isn't actually that much work, and gives you complete control on positioning, style etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your font has incorrect metrics. [Understanding UIFont](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/02/understanding-uifont/) has a good overview of what each metric means. Compare the font metrics you get from your font to the font metrics for system fonts and see if anything appears significantly wrong.