# NavigationBar's title showing only the half-top

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationbar

To make a long story short, that's what I get:

http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/9461/capturedcran20130418000x.png

Here is some code from my AppDelegate:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"main_bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  //[UIColor colorWithRed:125.0/255.0 green:111.0/255.0 blue:100.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
  //UITextAttributeTextColor,
  //[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8],
  //UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
  //[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)],
  //UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Pacifico" size:25],
  UITextAttributeFont,
  nil]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:-10 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

What can possibly be the problem ?

Comment: If Pacifico is a custom font the problem is iOS isn't centering it correctly in the y-axis which will lead to it getting cutoff, see my post on the subject [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5319157/155513)

Comment: it looks more like the label gets cut. So my approach would be to create a UILabel, make its size as big as the navBar size, set the default title to nil and just add your label to the navbar.

Comment: Yes Pacifico is a custom font. What method should I use ? (I always get the same error: unrecognized selector sent to instance...)

Comment: The problem is that I've to put dynamic title according to user's choice... Seems not possible with your solution @pmk

Comment: Can i see the code of when you are adding the text to the nav bar?

Comment: The text is set in the storyboard, should i change for programatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar problems and sorted them out by using something like this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Home";
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"main_bar.png"];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 44);
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
        label.shadowColor = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Pacifico" size:25];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
        label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Remindbox", @"");
    }
    return self;
}
```

You will need to tweek this a bit to get it to work with your font. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Anytime, glad I could help. Changing it dynamically isn't a problem. You could either put this in another method and make a property that you set before segue. Or you could override ´initWithNibName´ and add an NSString and use that to set the title.